# Rewrite Engine Route Conflict

Tags: laravel, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm writing a web application in laravel and have it almost working.
The only thing that is stopping me right now is the Rewrite Engine from apache ruining one particular route.

- Route it should be: http://example.org/publicaties
- Route it's
  rewritten to: http://example.org/public

publicaties == publication but in dutch.

I'm using the following rewrite code as this is mostly the default for laravel if not completely:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks

**Solved**

Turns out laravel doesn't like similar names like 'publicaties' and 'publications' because after changing the url, the issue was gone. Thanks all!

Comment: Did you install Laravel inside of the public directory of your server? Because that would be a security risk. I personally use a symlink instead of a htaccess redirect to use Laravel in a subfolder

Comment: What makes you think it is the Apache-level rewrites which are causing the problem, rather than the PHP-level routing? It sounds to me like the URL is matching two different routes in your application. Since the code shown doesn't define any individual routes, or mention the string "public", it looks very likely that the cause is somewhere else we can't see.

Comment: @GertB. Not sure to be completely honest. If you mean the html folder from httpd then yes.

Comment: @IMSoP I'm certain that there's no 2 identical routes on the application level but I do recall having issues with 2 very similar routes (publications and publicaties). By switching these routes around though, this issue was no more. Also, if the issue was on application level, wouldn't I notice it during development? Or am I missing something? I'm working on windows and deploying on linux so I might be.

Comment: If you find a beginner's guide to rewrite rules, you'll see that the rules you've shown are extremely simple, and can't possibly account for the problem. So wherever the problem is, it's not in the code shown. If you don't have any other Apache-level configuration, that means it's in the PHP code. So I suggest going back to the actual symptom (which you don't directly describe), and working out how to debug it - what URL does Laravel see? what is the pattern for the route that matches? etc